# storing a text file into array but it only prints out the last line

Tags: c

When I want to try to store some lines in the array from the text file it only prints the last line of the text file many times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char str[1000];
    char a[3][1000];

    fp = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file ");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(str, 1000, fp) != 0) {
        printf("%s", str);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        strcpy(a[i], str);
        printf("\n%s\n", a[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

my text file

stan nu'est

nu'est stan

nu'est ot5

minhyun is a nu'est member

It only prints minhyun is a nu'est member 3 times.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Well... Yes. In that second loop where you populate the `a` array, you copy the value of `str` every time, and that value never changes.

Comment: You also write to 4 elements of a 3 element long array, which causes *undefined behavior* which is a bad thing.

Comment: Since the data stored at `str` only changes in the fgets() loop, you might wish to copy the value there.  Remember, `foo bar[3]` is an array of three elements, and only `bar[0]`, `bar[1]`, and `bar[2]` exist.

Comment: @NominalAnimal omg really thank you so much I did put the strcpy in the fgets() loop and it's woking now

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Could not open file ");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function, then should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred. the function: `perror( "my error message" );` performs all the above correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
while (fgets(str, 1000, fp) != 0) {
        printf("%s", str); // 
    }
```

stan nu'est

nu'est stan

nu'est ot5

and then after the end of while loop the str will store only the last line, which is

minhyun is a nu'est member

int the below written for loop, minhyun is a nu'est member will be copied to the a[i] for 4 times and printed.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        strcpy(a[i], str);
        printf("\n%s\n", a[i]);
    }
```

to Copy the entire text to the array str, you may use below given code,

```
char kr;
    int i=0;
    do{
        kr=fgetc(fp);
        str[i++]=kr;
    }while(kr!=EOF);
    str[i]='\0';
```

and, to read the first three line of the text into the str array in order, you can use below given code.

```
int j=0,k;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++,j++)
    {
        for(k=0;str[j]!='\n'&&str[j]!='\0';j++,k++)
            a[i][k]=str[j];
        a[i][k]='\0';
        printf("\n%s\n", a[i]);
    }
```

Here is the entire code below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[1000];
    char a[3][1000];

    fp=fopen("filename.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file ");
        return 1;
    }

    char kr;
    int i=0;
    do{
        kr=fgetc(fp);
        str[i++]=kr;
    }while(kr!=EOF);
    str[i]='\0';

    int j=0,k;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++,j++)
    {
        for(k=0;str[j]!='\n'&&str[j]!='\0';j++,k++)
            a[i][k]=str[j];
        a[i][k]='\0';
        printf("\n%s\n", a[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```